# How to model this explicitly?

Tags: modeling, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

I have the following data: Levels of a specific microRNA, levels of two proteins that I have prior evidence are both regulated by this microRNA, and diagnostic stages of a disorder that is associated with levels of this protein (again theoretically based association). The diagnostic stages are a multinomial variable. The rest are continuous variables. So, I have the following crude model.

[image: the informal model]

How do I explicitly test this model in R (my preferred package)? A model with only the proteins and diagnostic stages I could test with "multinom" from nnet: Diagnosis ~ protein1 + protein2. But how do I add the miRNA -> protein1 and miRNA -> protein2 portions? I have seen diagrams that resemble this under "structural equation modeling", but is that what I actually want? I have also come across mediated models, but it looks like they don't model quite what I want given the "double" effect of the miRNA.

Comment: Hi, as you mentioned, SEM looks suitable for this analysis. You can use [lavaan](https://lavaan.ugent.be) package in R.

Comment: Does lavaan handle multinomial logistic models?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part, good point. And no, as far as I remember, `lavaan` cannot estimate multinomial logistic regression models. I guess you can use MPlus in this case. Maybe Stata's `gsem` can handle that too.

Comment: Oh, lovely, now I need to learn yet another software package (hoping that my institution has a license).